# How is it you create an Applet Project in JDeveloper 11g?

Tags: java, menu, applet, oracle11g, jdeveloper

I am attempting to create an Applet however cannot find the appropriate menu to do so.

Comment: Note 1) (J)Frame based apps. can be launched directly off the web using Java Webstart. 2)  Web based rich clients add another level of complexity to making rich clients.  If you cannot even find the 'menu item' for it, it does not bode well for the project.

Comment: Please could someone tell me where it is located or what plugins I need?